# Determining whether this equation is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given 2 sets of equations and I want to determine if they're linearly independent or not.

1. $e^{-x}, -2e^{2x}+5e^{-x}$
2. $x|x|, x^2$

The definition of linear independence: if there are no constants $a, b \not= 0$ such that $ax_1(t)+bx_2(t)=0$. For the first set of equations, I can tell that this is linearly independent because of the term $-2e^{2x}$ will never go away. For the second set of equations, I'm not so sure. If $x \geq 0$, then this equation is not linearly independent. But $x \geq 0$ is not stated as a restriction. I just need someone to hopefully confirm my findings and see if my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: for the first one, what if you put a coefficient of $0$ in front of $-2e^{2x}$? Then it may go away!

Comment: For the first, one can compute the Wronskian. For the second (and for the first), you can try evaluating a linear combination of the two functions at two different $x$'s and see if you can show that $a$ and $b$ must both be zero.

Comment: Take two "random" values of $x$ and check if you obtain a zero determinant. ($0, \ln2$ and $-1,1$ are conclusive.)

Comment: Ok....I see my mistake now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the domain of the function is not specified I will take it as the whole real line.

Suppose $ae^{-x}+b(-2e^{2x}+5e^{-x})=0$. Divide throughout by $e^{2x}$ and take limit as $ x \to \infty$. You get $b=0$ from  which you can see that $a$ must also be $0$. Hence, the first see is linearly independent.

Suppose $ax|x|+bx^{2}=0$. Put $x=1$ to get $a+b=0$ and $x=-1$ to get $-a+b=0$. Use these two equations to show that $a=b=0$. So the second set is also linearly independent.